# Deduce template parameter based on std::function argument type from lambda

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

Is there any way to pass a lambda to a function template which takes a `std::function<void(T)>` argument, and have the `T` template parameter deduced from the argument of the lambda, rather than having to explicitly state it?

That is, given a lambda of the form `[](std::string){...}`, deduce `T` is `std::string`?

**Example:**

So with a function template

```
template<typename T>
void func(std::function<void(T)> f) { ... }
```

I can call func by **explicitly specifying `std::string`** as follows:

```
func<std::string>([](std::string){...});
```

I would like to **deduce `std::string`**, and call func as follows:

```
func([](std::string){...});
```

**Examplar app below:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void func(std::function<void(const T&)> f)
{
    T m = "hello world";
    f(m);
}

struct foo
{
    void bar(std::string msg)
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << ": " << msg << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;

    // explicit specification works
    func<std::string>([&](const std::string& m) {
        f.bar(m);
    });

    // relying on argument deduction fails
//  func([&](const std::string& m) {
//      f.bar(m);
//  });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `std::function` for parameters.

Comment: Agreed, thanks @Yuushi - voted to close

Comment: @Rapptz - what would you use? I know I can do this: `template<typename T, typename Func> void func(Func f)`, but I still need to call `func<std::string>(...)`

Comment: C++ doesn't have a sane way to get the arguments of a callable. You can get a hack working for a limited subset but it's typically frowned down upon.

Comment: @Rapptz - so what would you suggest?